# Angular subscribe cannot read properties of undefined at interval

Tags: angular, setinterval, subscription, angular-material-table

I'm trying to automatically update a `mat-table` every five seconds. Upon first loading the site, the `getDrinks()` method of the `PrijslijstComponent` works without issue and loads the table.

When calling it from the `interval` every five seconds after initial loading though, it gives the following error:

[image: Error]

There were a few posts on this type of errors, but nothing which seemed to solve my problem. I tried to do a console log inside the `getDrinksByGroup()` method, but nothing at all gets executed there, it seems, before throwing the error.

I'm wondering where I'm going wrong as the first `getDrinks()` call works, but none after that. Also, I'm not sure if this is how I should update the `mat-table` regularly?

prijslijst.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource, MatTableDataSourcePaginator} from '@angular/material/table';
import { DrinksService } from '../drinks/drinks.service';
import { Drink } from '../drinks/drink';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-prijslijst',
  templateUrl: './prijslijst.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./prijslijst.component.css']
})
export class PrijslijstComponent {
  private alcohols: Drink[] = [];
  private nonAlcohols: Drink[] = [];
  private interval: any;
  dataSourceAlcohol!: MatTableDataSource<Drink, MatTableDataSourcePaginator>;
  dataSourceNonAlcohol!: MatTableDataSource<Drink, MatTableDataSourcePaginator>;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'startPrice', 'currentPrice', 'numberSold'];

  constructor(private drinksService: DrinksService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getDrinks();
    this.interval = setInterval(this.getDrinks, 5000);
  }


  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.interval) {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
 }

  getDrinks() {
    console.log('Getting drinks')
    this.drinksService
        .getDrinksByGroup()
        .subscribe(({alcohols, notAlcohols}) => {
          if(alcohols !== undefined) {
            this.alcohols = alcohols;
          }
          if(notAlcohols !== undefined) {
            this.nonAlcohols = notAlcohols;
          }
          this.dataSourceAlcohol = new MatTableDataSource(this.alcohols);
           this.dataSourceNonAlcohol = new MatTableDataSource(this.nonAlcohols);
    });
  }

  addOrder(drink: Drink) {
    drink.numberInOrder = drink.numberInOrder + 1;
  }
}
```

drinks.service.ts

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { map, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Drink } from './drink';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DrinksService {
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  private url: string = 'http://localhost:3000/drinks';
  drinks: Drink[] = [];

  setupDrinks(): void {
    this.getDrinks().subscribe(drinks => {
      drinks.forEach(drink => this.drinks.push(drink))
    });
  }

  getDrinks(): Observable<Drink[]> {
    console.log('Getting drinks from backend')
    return this.http.get<Drink[]>(this.url);
  }

  getDrinksByGroup(): Observable<{alcohols: Drink[], notAlcohols: Drink[] }> {
    return this.getDrinks().pipe(map(drinks => {
      const alcoholDrinks: Drink[] = [];
      const notAlcoholDrinks: Drink[] = [];
      
      drinks.forEach(drink => {
        if(drink.alcohol) {
          alcoholDrinks.push(drink);
        } else {
          notAlcoholDrinks.push(drink)
        }
      });
      

      return { alcohols: alcoholDrinks, notAlcohols: notAlcoholDrinks };
    }));
  }

  setSoldOut(drinkName: string) {
    this.drinks.filter((drink) => {
      if(drink.name === drinkName) {
        drink.soldOut = true;
      }
    })
  }

  setDrinks(drinks: Drink[]) {
    this.drinks = drinks;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is in `this` object. Thats why you got undefined value.

Basically when setInterval callback fires, it will go in `getDrinks` function but `this` object in that function is not what you think it is.

You can either do something like:

```
// Explicitly bind `this` object to the scope that you want (component)
this.interval = setInterval(this.getDrinks.bind(this), 5000);
```

or :

```
// Arrow function automatically bind `this` object to its lexical (wrapping scope)
this.interval = setInterval(() = this.getDrinks(), 5000);
```

Or do it in a "right" way, and that is to use reactive approach (rxjs is for that) such as:

```
  destroy$ = new Subject();
  
  ngOnInit() {
    

    // Trigger timer each 5seconds (with 0 as first argument it will trigger first time without delay)
    timer(0, 5000)
      .pipe(
        // Call your service
        switchMap(_ => this.drinksService.getDrinksByGroup()),
        // Unsubscribe on ngDestroy
        takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe((result) => {

      }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
```

Comment: All these solutions do indeed work, thanks for the detailed explanation. Can you please clarify what scope the original `this` was? I thought it would be the component scope. 

Also, this is the first I learned about the Subject in rxjs (I'm very new to Angular). Why are we calling the `Subject.next()` method at all? Can't we just `.complete()` it without calling `.next()`?

Comment: Scope would be bound to the object that called that function. Set interval is defined on window global object. setInterval() and window.setInterval() would be the same.  It would be easier for you if you put debugger in your callback function and see what is the context.
takeUntil works with next() event of inner observable and not complete event.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is on this line:

```js
this.interval = setInterval(this.getDrinks, 5000);
```

Just replace it by:

```js
this.interval = setInterval(() => this.getDrinks(), 5000);
```

and it will work